# CSS footer width not full width

Tags: html, css

I've been fiddling with some html and css for some time - to try and make a responsive layout.  However, there is an issue when the header contains some content that pushes the width out, and the footer looks like it has some whitespace to the right when scroll bars are visible.

[image: bad layout]

How can I make the footer keep the same width as the window?

**NOTE:**  I had the issue whilst using some flex layout in the header, but tried to keep things simple so I am forcefully setting the width of the `ul` to 400 pixels.

### my code:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  min-height: 100%;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
  margin-block-end: 0;
  margin-inline-start: 0;
  margin-inline-end: 0;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}

main {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

ul,
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 100%;
}


/* force bigger width */

ul {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Html5 Structure</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

  <style>

  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <header class="page-header">

    <nav class="site-nav-menu">
      <ul class="site-nav-menu__root">
        <li class="site-nav-menu__item">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="site-nav-menu__item">
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="site-nav-menu__item">
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <article></article>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="footer__copyright">
      © Copyright 2019
      <strong>Acme Ltd</strong>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your header styles.

Answer (score 1):

Add padding same as header

```
footer {
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: blueviolet;
padding-left: 3em;
padding-right: 3em;
width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: This also works.  But I guess I need to keep header and footer in sync with box sizing.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, try not to hard code anything with pixels. It will cause the page to be unresponsive. Use [Rems or percentages, here is an article that talks about CSS sizing units.](https://medium.com/code-better/css-units-for-font-size-px-em-rem-79f7e592bb97) The solution below should do the trick.

```
ul {
width: 100%;}

header {
left: 0;
right: 0;
background-color:pink;
padding-left: 0%;
padding-right: 0%;
width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Indeed. I just wanted to hack the ul width to force the issue. It didn't matter that the content in here was using flexbox with padded content which also caused the issue and not using any pixel widths.